# How to change a server side label display to Block in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How can I change the display property of my server side label to Block?

```
<asp:Label id="lblError" runat="server" style="display:none;"></asp:Label>

function block()
{
    // change display property to block
}
```

I tried

```
document.getElementById('lblError').style.display = "block";
```

but it's not working, please help me.

Comment: "its not working" doesn't give us any information about what happened when you tried it.

Comment: on button click i am calling block() function.

Comment: i want to show some 'hello' massage on label.

Comment: That doesn't say what *happens* though. You've got code, and you've said it's not doing what you *want* it to do, but you haven't said what it *does* do.

Comment: @amit...Did you check the following answers ??

Comment: @amit...So why didn't any feedback ?? Would you like to accept one of them if they solved your issue ??

Comment: @amit please mark as answerd (using the green V sign) a correct answer

Answer (score 1):

use [ClientIDMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) :

```
<asp:Label id="lblerror" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" style="display:none;"></asp:Label>
```

and in client:

```
document.getElementById('lblerror').style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
document.getElementById('lblError').style.display = "block";
```

Or you can use a safer way:

```
var buttonID = '<%= lblError.ClientID %>';
var button = document.getElementById(buttonID);
if (button) { 
    button.style.display = 'block'; 
}
```

It also looks like youv'e missed a double quote after `style=`. It should be :

```
<asp:Label id="lblError" runat="server" style="display:none;"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to access a control from client script is to pass the value of the `ClientID` property of the server control to the `document.getElementById` method. Like this:

```
document.getElementById('<%= lblerror.ClientID %>').style.display = "block";
```

Have a look at this: [`How to: Access Controls from JavaScript by ID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410598.aspx).